# Como fazer TabLayout dinâmico no Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

Eu criei uma tablayout na minha aplicação, eu preciso que ao clicar em uma das opções do menu, automaticamente ele assuma a posição 0.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde ficaria a casa seria um ícone de voltar e os demais seriam as categorias desse item em específico. Quando clicar novamente no primeiro item que seria o ícone de voltar ele volta um menu anterior.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei remover todas as tabelas ao selecionar uma das tabs e adicionar novas, mas da erro na aplicação. Segue como está a estrutura da tablayout:

xml

```
<com.conformidade.petrobras.apco.helper.CustomTabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
</com.conformidade.petrobras.apco.helper.CustomTabLayout>
```

código

```
 //Configura Menu
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_white_24dp));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Menu 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Menu 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Menu 3"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Menu 4"));


        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new CustomTabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(CustomTabLayout.Tab tab) {
                mostrarSubCategorias(tab);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(CustomTabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(CustomTabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

Método para recarregar tabelas (Aqui ele da erro no tabLayout.removeTabAt(j) )

```
private void mostrarSubCategorias(CustomTabLayout.Tab tab) {
        int totalTabs = tabLayout.getTabCount();
        int i = tab.getPosition();
        for (int j = 0; j < totalTabs; j++) {
            if (j != i) {
                tabLayout.removeTabAt(j);
            }
        }
        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_return_white_24dp).setText("");
    }
```

Alguém tem ideia de outra forma de fazer isso? Porque as categorias serão dinâmicas vindas de um banco de dados onde um administrador poderá excluir ou adicionar novas categorias com sub-categorias a qualquer momento.

Comment: Ola @SanOli, não altere a pergunta para indicar que/como o problema foi resolvido. Se você achou uma resposta diferente das propostas pela comunidade, você pode responder sua própria pergunta. Voltei a versão da sua pergunta para a [revisão 5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/390776/revisions). Vale apena você dar uma olhada no nosso [Tour]. =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pergunta não foi respondida, mas eu consegui descobrir qual o problema, no loop ele estava buscando as tabs a partir do primeiro index. Acontece que após remover as primeiras o index das outras tabs mudavam e dava erro exatamente depois da metade do número total. Eu apenas fiz o método buscar a partir da última posição e ir removendo. Atualizado na pergunta para quem quiser fazer algo parecido.

Método para recarregar tabelas:

**Como estava:**

> Aqui ele da erro no tabLayout.removeTabAt(j)

```
private void mostrarSubCategorias(CustomTabLayout.Tab tab) {
        int totalTabs = tabLayout.getTabCount();
        int i = tab.getPosition();
        for (int j = 0; j < totalTabs; j++) {
            if (j != i) {
                tabLayout.removeTabAt(j);
            }
        }
        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_return_white_24dp).setText("");
    }
```

**Método atualizado:**

```
private void mostrarSubCategorias(CustomTabLayout.Tab tab) {
    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_return_white_24dp).setText("");
    int totalTabs = tabLayout.getTabCount();
    int i = tab.getPosition();
    for (int j = totalTabs - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (j != i) {
            tabLayout.removeTabAt(j);
        }
    }
    //Aqui pode adicionar as novas tabelas
 }
```